# Meteor Blaze helper and Mongo collection.find with Session key selector

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

This Meteor code uses Meteor Blaze template helper that supplies some html elements with data from mongo collection.

The `collection.findOne` has `Session.get` as the selector so that when there is no value for the Session key then I get an empty object to the template so that I get no data i.e. blank element. But I still get values in some elements. mainly the editable `div` and `span` and one `input` elements as commented in the html file.

Where did I go wrong?
I am trying to clean the "form" when I fire an event by setting the `Session.set('plate', '')` i.e. blank value for the session key 'plate', empty object, no data for the Blaze template, clears the elements, right?
Thank you

```js
//client/main.js

Meteor.startup(function(){
  listenToEvents()
})

///// globle listener /////
function listenToEvents(){
  $('.new').on('click', function(e){
    let elementId = $(this).parents('div')[2].id 
    if(elementId == 'vehicle'){
      Session.set('plate','') //<<< used in mongo collection selector
    }
  })
}


///// Blaze helper /////
Template.vehicle.helpers({
  'vehicle' : function(){
    if(Session.get('plate') == undefined){
      console.log('no plate selected')
      return
    }
    let searchForPlate = { "$regex" : Session.get('plate') , "$options" : "i"} // set to '' by event above 
    let vehicle = Vehicles.findOne({'plate': searchForPlate})

    if(!vehicle){ 
      console.log('empty vehicle object')
      return {}
    }
    console.log('vehcile selected: ', vehicle)
    
    if(vehicle.vin.length == 17){ 
      vehicle.vin_a = vehicle.vin.substr(0, 9)
    }
    vehicle.remain = Math.round(diff)
    if(diff <= 0) vehicle.expired = true
 
    return vehicle
  }
})
```

```html
<template name="vehicle">
  <div id="vehicle" class="subject-container" >

    <div class="section-head">
      <div class="control">
        <button class="toggle">-</button>
        <button class="new">N</button>
      </div>
      <div>
      <!-- the next input does not get cleared -->
        <input id="plate" type="text" size="6" placeholder="plate" value={{vehicle.plate}}>
        
        <!-- the next span does not get cleared -->
        <span data-expired={{vehicle.expired}}>{{vehicle.remain}} {{vehicle.expiry}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="body">
      <!-- the next div does not get cleared -->
      <div id="vin" class="editable" contenteditable="true">{{vehicle.vin_a}}<span id="vinb">{{vehicle.vin_b}}</span><span id="vin4">{{vehicle.vin4}}</span></div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="YR, make, modle" value={{vehicle.info}}>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no, an empty regex matches everything. This is easy to test if you open a mongo shell and run a query like that against any collection with content:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.users.find({_id: {$regex: ''}}).count()
2723
```

I would just explicitly guard against that case, which you can easily do like this:

```
    if (!Session.get('plate')){
      console.log('no plate selected')
      return
    }
```